# Campo de e-mail simples no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu criei um campo input para receber e-mail e minha única exigência é garantir que tenha um "@" e pelo menos um ".". 
Li vários REGEX para fazer essa validação, mas todos são complexos demais e eu possuo endereços de e-mail bem curtos na servidor interno aqui da empresa, então a maioria dos REGEX prontos não me servem.

Segue meu form

```
<b>E-mail: </b><input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" size="30" Onkeyup="valida()" required />
```

Segue meu javascript até o momento:

```
function valida(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    email = /^[\w!#$%&'*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+)*@(([\w-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}|\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}\])$/.toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("email").value = email;

}
```

Grato pela colaboração

Comment: Pq simplesmente não coloca `type="email"` nesse input??

Comment: @hugocsl, servidor legado com HTML 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz essa modificação da resposta acima, que me atendeu plenamente:

```
function valida(){
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
email = email.toLowerCase();

if(email.search(/@/) != -1 && email.search(/./) != -1){
    document.getElementById("email").value = email;
    }
else{
    alert('Digite um e-mail válido');
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um `regex` e usar o metodo `search` que busca na string o `regex` criado.
no exemplo eu busco na string o `@` e um `.` 
caso exista `@`na string ele retorna a posição em que esta. caso contraio retorna -1.
Basicamente eu vejo se o `search` por `@` e por `.` é diferente de -1, se for o email é valido.

```js
let email = document.querySelector('input[type=email]');

function validation() {
if(!email.value) { return console.log('digite algum valor!'); }
  rgx(email.value);
    
}

function rgx(value) {
    if(value.search(/@/) != -1 && value.search(/./) != -1) {
        return console.log('email valido')
    } else {
        return console.log('email invalido')
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="email">
<button onclick="validation()">valida</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado! me ajudou muito!